# Dynamic SQL with Parameter in FROM clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Executing a block of dynamic SQL via sp_executesql, where the @Database1 variable is a parameter of the stored procedure.

```
 SET @SQL = ''
 SET @SQL =
'SELECT @@SERVERNAME, @DB, ''Schema name'', s.name, t.name, stype.Name, scol.length 
 INTO   ##TableList
 FROM   '+@DB+'.sys.tables t

INNER JOIN '+@DB+'.sys.schemas s
  ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DB UNIQUEIDENTIFIER', @DB = @Database1
```

However I am unsure how to use the parameter from the sp_executesql call, in the from clause of the dynamic SQL. Is it possible to do this or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: If this is just a test or an internal thing, perhaps consider using `sp_MSforeachtable`. It's undocumented/could be retired at any time, but does exactly what you're trying to do. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2010/06/27/example-code-executing-tsql-for-each-table-in-a-database.aspx) an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this procedure:
Don't know what ''Schema name'' is, so I leave it. Try to change it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]

(
  @DB            VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max);

BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #TableList(
                SERVERNAME NVARCHAR(255), 
                DB NVARCHAR(255), 
                Schema_name  NVARCHAR(255), 
                s_name  NVARCHAR(255), 
                t_name  NVARCHAR(255), 
                stype_Name  NVARCHAR(255), 
                scol_length INTEGER);

    SET @SQL ='INSERT INTO #TableList(
                           SERVERNAME,
                           DB,
                           Schema_name,  
                           s_name,  
                           t_name,  
                           stype_Name, 
                           scol_length)
               SELECT      @@SERVERNAME, 
                           @DB, 
                           ''Schema name'', 
                           s.name, 
                           t.name, 
                           stype.Name, 
                           scol.length 
               FROM       [' + @DB + '].[sys].[tables] t
               INNER JOIN [' + @DB + '].[sys].[schemas] s ON (t.schema_id = s.schema_id)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL; 

SELECT SERVERNAME,
       DB,
       Schema_name,  
       s_name,  
       t_name,  
       stype_Name, 
       scol_length
FROM  #TableList

END
GO
```